# jQuery drag/drop items duplicating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<span:abc class=\"heading-1\">Heading 1</span> then something in the middle, with something in <strong>bold text</strong> at the end of the string.
```

I have wrapped the original tags in a custom span, and made the contenteditable="false".

By commenting out the original html/tag, the user only sees the css/marker. With this, I can then explode the posted contents, once the form is submitted and glue the original tags with the edited text. This is done with PHP.

The issue with this, is that although the code is nearly there, the draggable/droppable (pink) tags duplicate when dropping, and I'm not sure how to "pair them up", so that the start tag is always before the end tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/gXScu/185/.

Comment: You have a typo (starPos instead of startPos) somewhere. I don't have time atm to look for the actual problems :-)

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann Thanks, corrected the typo at line 51, but it doesn't seem to correct the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/gXScu/186/